# Is it ok to put HTML into HTML attributes?

Tags: html

I want a place to store markup for my tooltips. I thought of `data-*` attributes, it works, but I wonder if its wrong or may cause problems ...

```
<a href="#" 
   title="You can edit project details like name & description" 
   data-tip="<h6>Edit Project</h6><p>You can edit project details like name &amp; description here</p>">
   Edit
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fine; a minor side-effect is that `data-*` properties are invalid in HTML 4. There's nothing you can do about this except (mis)using some other existing property, which is usually worse than not passing validation.

Escaping `>` to `&gt;` is recommended to prevent problems with broken HTML parsers. [Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/charset.html#h-5.2)

Escaping `&` to `&amp;` as you already do is necessary for it to be valid HTML (if the `&` is not followed by a space and thus forms an entity, cheers @bobince)

Obviously, you *must* escape `"` to `&quot;` to prevent the HTML from breaking.

Comment: Actually you can get away without escaping `&` either, in this case. When followed by a space (or various other characters) the unescaped `&` is valid. Obviously it's totally inadvisable, and not valid in XHTML, but then the same is true of leaving `<` unescaped.

Comment: Arguably the `&` in the tip should really be written as `&amp;amp;`, because it's HTML markup *inside* another layer of HTML markup! Argh. I think I'd include this as a separate shown/hidden element instead of hiding it in an attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes can contain parsed data (including character references), so holding HTML  in a custom attribute is fine.

The problems I can see is with terminating the string early. So long as you encode quotes, you will be fine.